# How to highlight the whole word in bold

Tags: php

There is a suggestion: teg are divided into two categories.

code:

```
echo preg_replace("/($word)/i","<b>$1</b>", htmlspecialchars($words[i])."<br>";
```

If a word, such as a teg, only highlights it in bold. How to highlight an entire word, using the code above, highlights only part of the category

Comment: So you want to highlight all words that *contain* `$word`, not just `$word` right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @vasdadsadas What if the word is `es` and the text we have is `test`? Would you still wish to highlight `test`?

Comment: the word must match, I just took the wrong example

Comment: @vasdadsadas Ok, so if it is a sentence like `This is a test sentence` and the word you have is `es`, so the output should be `<b>This is a test sentence</b>` or `This is a <b>test</b> sentence` ?

Comment: This is a <b>test</b> sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given context, you can perform a match of the word you are looking for with matching optional non-space characters before or after it surrounded by a word boundary like below:

```
<?php

$str = 'HTML-document';

$word = 'HTML';

echo preg_replace('/\b[^\s]*'.preg_quote($word).'[^\s]*\b/',"<b>$0</b>", $str);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/7411d)

Comment: if the word is HTML and sentence is HTML-document, highlights only HTML

Comment: @vasdadsadas Ok, so a word can also have non-word characters?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: for some reasons when i have word html and for some reason it turns out &lt;html></html>;

Comment: @vasdadsadas That's because you also use `htmlspecialchars` too.

Comment: and how to fix?

Comment: @vasdadsadas Can you share a link to your snippet so that I can try?

Comment: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/febb2

Comment: @vasdadsadas Ok, what is your expected output?

Comment: this <<b>html</b>>

Comment: for some reason it inserts the character < in advance  &<b>lt;

Comment: @vasdadsadas Ok, but now your requirement is unclear. You will have to list all possible testcases by editing your question. Why replace `<html>` as `<<b>html</b>>` as it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: to make it work properly how to close >

Comment: something puts in front of this symbol &<b>, sorry <b><html></b>

Comment: @vasdadsadas Sorry, your requirement is unclear. I am afraid I can't be of any further help.

Comment: it doesn't see symbol &, I added and it worked /&?\b[^\s]*